# Value at Risk and Expected Shortfall

Tags: probability

Event A B and C are independent and each has a probability of 0.1. There will be \$200 000 loss if any of these events occur, if two of these events occur there will be a loss of \$400,000 and if all three occur the loss will be \$600,000.

Find Value at Risk and Expected Shortfall at 0.98 confidence interval.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the character \$ is special around here.

Comment: The number of events occur follows a Binomial distribution, and the corresponding loss is equal to $200000$ times the number of events occur. From this you calculate the required quantile of this loss distribution as the VaR, and apply the definition for the expected shortfall also.